# Property TipoServicio::$tipo_usuario does not exist, where is that property?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've this Form defined:

```
class NaturalFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
                ....
                ->add('servicio', 'entity', array(
                    'mapped' => FALSE,
                    'class' => 'ComunBundle:TipoServicio',
                    'property' => 'nombre',
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'label' => FALSE,
                    'expanded' => TRUE,
                    'multiple' => TRUE
                ));
    }
    ...
}
```

And this is the definition for `TipoServicio` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="nomencladores.tipo_servicio", schema="nomencladores")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Sencamer\ComunBundle\Entity\Repository\TipoServicioRepository")
 */
class TipoServicio
{

    protected $id;
    protected $nombre;
    protected $activo = true;
    protected $cedula_benef_sisgesp;

    ... setters/getters function above

}
```

Any time I try to build the form on the controller:

```
public function naturalAction() {
    $entity = new Natural();
    $form = $this->createForm(new NaturalFormType(), $entity, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('guardar-registro')));
    return array('entity' => $entity, 'form' => $form->createView());
}
```

I get this error:

> Property ComunBundle\Entity\TipoServicio::$tipo_usuario does not exist

Why? What I'm doing wrong or what I'm not seeing in my code?

I clear the cache several times and run the command `cache:clear` and `cache:warmup` without success.

- PS: I deleted some parts from code for easier reading and do the code less extensive
- PS1: Sorry for the spanish language on some parts but this code is for a spanish client so he wants her code on spanish (ugly for me but clients always have the reason)

**EDIT**

Search for `$tipo_usuario`:

[image]

Search for `tipo_usuario`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to get this `tipo_usuario` property somewhere.

In where file and line this error is throw ? Do you have the full stack trace ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this [address](http://190.200.150.181:8080/sencamer/web/app_dev.php/registro/natural) you can see the full stack trace there and this is the problem I can't find where this property is called

Comment: Can't figurate the problem... Did you try a full search of `tipo_usuario` on your project to find a clue ?

Comment: I added some info to the main post about the search you asked me, did you need any other thing?

Comment: Nevermind I don't know what happen but after restart Apache service all works again some thread stucked or don't know the real cause is not the first time I  got that kind of problem